# MSSQL How to merge rows in single table

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, merge

I am really a newbie when it comes to programming. I've been working with a web application written in C# MVC5.  I am using MSSQL for my database and some programming models such as Linq and Entity Framework.

What i need to work with as of now is the merging rows in a single table that has the same contents.

for example
I have the following tables with the following columns:

table **contact_type**

```
[socialId][socialName][webUrlTemplate]
```

table **rated_merge**

```
[mergeId][timestamp][ratedId]
```

table 

rated*

```
[ratedId][fname][lname][mergeId][ratings]
```

table **rated_contact

```
[id][ratedId][socialId][value]
```

I have a form wherein the user can enter their social networking/dating site username/id, in which submitted, the contents of the form will be saved to tables **rated** and **rated_contact.**

upon submission of the form, it will check first if the form has matching records in **rated** and **rated_contact** tables. 
if there is no matching records, the form contents will be save as a new record.

But if there is a match, this is where merging will happen
(matching happens only when the system detects if a username from the from matches any username in the database). Matching rows will be compared, a new record will be created containing all the differences and matches from the rows compared. Then the previous records will be marked as deleted. This new record will complete the profile of the person rated.

After creating the merge, the column [ratedId] from table **rated_contact** will be updated to the [ratedId] from the newly created merged record. Then with the **rated_merge** table I need to insert a new record containing the [timestamp], [ratedId] and [mergeId] which is an auto increment field.

I need to get the [mergeId] and update the [mergeId] column in the **rated** table for all the matching records.

Any suggestion on what approach should I do?

Thanks guys.

Comment: do you have any common ID? which uniquely identifies user iirespective  of that user provided twitter,facebook id?

Comment: i have to ask, why is it that these "duplicate" rows exist in the first place? How are they being inserted into the database in the first instance

Comment: @Viru yes, each name has a corresponding userId as the primary key.

Comment: @Takarii the application is a people ratings app. a person rated can be rated multiple times by many user, that's why there's a possibility to have duplicate rows that exist in the table. (^_^)

Comment: So when you get the second row? do you know for which user id that second row is?

Comment: ok, but if a person can be rated, then they have a unique identifier. Why isnt an update operation being done instead? Each person is unique, so why allow duplicates in the first place?

Comment: @Takarii Yeah...correct..thats where I was headed with my questions....Update Operation should be way to go..

Comment: this table holds the record for all the social networking site the person being "rated" is registered. there is a separate table for rated persons' which contains their personal details (userId, age, birthday, fullname,city etc). userId is used as a foreign key in the table given above.

Comment: so why arent you using `UPDATE` instead?

Comment: You should be checking this table for the existence of the FK based on the PK from your initial table, then if it exists you update the row, otherwise you insert. This whole duplicate row situation shouldnt exist in the first place.

Comment: actually, my table is a little more complicated than mentioned above, i only made it simple in order for me to get the idea how to merge records in a single table.

Comment: You need to post enough information for us to help. If you havent included relevant linking information we cant supply and answer. However, my previous comment still stands - the issue should never have been a problem to begin with

Comment: next i need to ask, for each person, could you have multiple facebook id's ie, 4 rows with [facebook_id][null][null]

Comment: in that case yes. the table mentioned above can contain multiple social networking id's but when the system detects that the social id for that person is already existing that social id will never be used.

Comment: so what happens if the social id is detected? does it decide to enter a row with all null values? Can a person have more than one social id in each area? (3 facebook id's for example)

Comment: I'm ready to write an answer for you, but the answer i give will be based on whether or not this is a live and active system with data, or still in design and using dummy details

Comment: I edited the question guys, hope you can understand. sorry for my english

Comment: You are still doing this backwards. You need to seriously consider how you are updating the database with new information - Adding and deleting rows that are duplicates is terrible practice. There shouldnt be duplicates in the first instance

Comment: You should be using your FK's as a reference row to update and not inserting any extras. If the FK exists, you UPDATE the row with the additional entries.

Comment: `rated_contact` should contain all the columns needed to link back to `rated` This what when user 1 enters another ID, it can search `rated_contact` to see if the USER exists in that table. if it doesnt, it adds a new record. If it exists, then it updates the relevant column with the relevant socialD

Answer (score -1):

You may use this query

```
select fullname,max(facebook_id) facebook_id,max(twitter_id)twitter_id,max(insta_id)insta_id from member group by fullname
```

Answer (score -1):

```
insert into table_to_insert 
([fullname],[facebook_id],[twitter_id],[insta_id])
select [fullname],isnull(t1.[facebook_id],t2.[facebook_id]),isnull(t1.[twitter_id],t2.[twitter_id]),isnull(t1.[insta_id],t2.[insta_id])
from tablesource1 t1
inner join
tablesource2 t2
on t1.fullname=t2.fullanme
```

Maybe it will help you

Comment: Because there was no id in your table so int this case your example say the name is the point you want to join and write id-s to the name. So pleas specify how do you think it will work with out an unique id?

Comment: first of all..I have not asked this question..Check comments on question...I did ask OP if there is unique ID and he has mentioned that there is unique user id....so you should also have clarified with user before posting incorrect answer